# Not able to display the raw contents of a file with Spring Boot REST API, Thymeleaf and JS fetch

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, fetch-api

I have a `Spring Boot` application which on load of Home page (`http://localhost:8080`) displays all the filenames within a specific directory on the browser successfully without any issues.

Now, I would like to make those filenames a hyperlink, clicking on which would display the content of that file on the browser.

I am getting a `JS` error when I do so. The request is not even reaching to the server. Is there something wrong with the way I am calling the function and passing filename parameter in it?

**Error:**

```
VM164:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: database.properties is not defined
at <anonymous>:1:17
```

**HomeController.java**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping({"", "/", "/home"})
    public String index(Model model) {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

**DirListController.java**

```
@RestController
public class DirListController {

    @Autowired
    private SshConnService sshConnService;

    @GetMapping("/api/dir")
    public List<String> showAllDirs(Model model) throws Exception {
        return sshConnService.listAllFiles(); //returns [database.properties, messaging.properties, ....]
    }

}
```

**RawFileContentController.java**

```
@RestController
public class RawFileContentController {

    @Autowired
    private SshConnService sshConnService;

    @GetMapping("/api/rawFileContent")
    public String showRawFileContent(@RequestParam(value = "filename") String filename) throws Exception {
        return sshConnService.catFile(filename);
    }

}
```

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Directory List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Directory List</h1>
        <table id="categoryTable" class="table" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <h2>File Contents</h2>
        <table id="contentTable" class="table" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>File Content</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script src="/webjars/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**js/main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    viewAllDirs();
});


/*** Show all files within a directory **/
async function viewAllDirs() {
    $('#categoryTable tbody').empty();
    const dirResponse = await dirService.findAll();
    const dirJson = dirResponse.json();
    dirJson.then(filename => {
        filename.forEach(filename => {
            console.log(filename);
            //make the filename clickable and display it's content onclick
            let categoryRow = `$(<tr><td><a href="javascript:viewFileContent(${filename})">${filename}</a></td></tr>)`;
            $('#categoryTable tbody').append(categoryRow);
        });
    });
}

const dirService = {
    findAll: async () => {
        return await fetch('/api/dir');
    }
};



/*** View File Contents **/
async function viewFileContent(filename) {
    $('#contentTable tbody').empty();
    const rawFileContentResponse = await rawFileContentService.findByFilename(filename);
    const rawFileContentResponseJson = rawFileContentResponse.json();
    console.log(rawFileContentResponseJson);
    let contentRow = `$(<tr><td>${rawFileContentResponseJson}</td></tr>)`;
    $('#contentTable tbody').append(contentRow);
}

const rawFileContentService = {
    findByFilename: async (filename) => {
        return await fetch('/api/rawFileContent?filename=' + filename);
    }
};
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I guess you didn't set up DB properties in Spring. Check it please.

Comment: If there is any stacktrace at the backend java could you please share that as well.

Comment: There is no DB attached to this as I am connecting to a Unix box via JSch.

Comment: @Ananthapadmanabhan - I am not seeing any errors on the server-side. I think this issue is related to JS only. May be I am not passing the parameters the correct way.

Comment: @Ananthapadmanabhan - The request is not even reaching the server.

Comment: @Nital If this is a JS issue could you try debugging it in the browser console to pinpoint the line of code which is causing this error. Also please paste the entire stactrace as given in the console.